# Parsing XML to get multiple values

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, flurry

I'm retrieving data from this XML:

```
<appMetrics versionName="1.1.0" startDate="2013-04-16" metric="ActiveUsersByDay" groupBy="dayOfYear" endDate="2013-04-18" country="US" version="1.0" generatedDate="4/19/13 10:10 AM">
<day value="6" date="2013-04-16"/>
<day value="4" date="2013-04-17"/>
<day value="2" date="2013-04-18"/>
</appMetrics>
```

I have been successful with simpler XMLs like if it was like this instead:

```
<appMetrics versionName="1.1.0" startDate="2013-04-16" metric="ActiveUsersByDay" groupBy="dayOfYear" endDate="2013-04-18" country="US" version="1.0" generatedDate="4/19/13 10:10 AM">
<day value="6"/>
<day value="4"/>
<day value="2"/>
</appMetrics>
```

How do I extract both the day value and date under the same single element?
What i've done in the past is just search for an element then copy the string, but there are multiple pieces so it doesnt work. Do I have to make it an array instead? Or is there a way to just take the day value and date separately?

Comment: Yes there're a lot of ways to get them separately. You can create an array if you want to. What's the problem with Xcode ?

Comment: Ive been trying to get the pieces out as a string so obviously it doesnt work when it's two pieces like that. How would i do it as an array?

Comment: Xcode is just the program you are using to write the code.  The question doesn't have anything to do with Xcode.  You'll get better results by tagging your questions with the programming language you are using.

Comment: All the parsers I know read XML as text, so there must be no problem to read string from string and that is certainly possible. Now without any code it's reasonably impossible to tell how or for what you are going to use an array, you might want to clarify it and add some code.

Comment: Basically I check the name of the element, then set whatever's in it as a string. But in this case it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSXMLParser`. In its delegate callback

```
parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
```

you can find all the attributes (like `value`, `date`) in the attributes dictionary.

**Edit**

Parsing is really easy. Just create a parser with your data, set self as delegate and start parsing. Maintain some mutable array where you read everything in.

See the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-57808) Reference and [NSXMLParserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008632-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) protocol.

If you need more help, go for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116827/looking-for-a-good-tutorial-on-nsxmlparser) with many links to tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You would parse it so that you get the following nested structure.

```
{
    "appMetrics": {
        "versionName": "1.1.0",
        "startDate": "2013-04-16",
        "metric": "ActiveUsersByDay",
        "groupBy": "dayOfYear",
        "endDate": "2013-04-18",
        "country": "US",
        "version": "1.0",
        "generatedDate": "4/19/13 10:10 AM",
        "day": [
            {
                "value": "6",
                "date": "2013-04-16"
            },
            {
                "value": "4",
                "date": "2013-04-17"
            },
            {
                "value": "2",
                "date": "2013-04-18"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You parse it using `NSXMLParser`, or if you're worried about performance, `libxml2` (for which `NSXMLParser` is just an Objective-C wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

Just tryout this....

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {          

 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"day"]) {
         currentValue = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"value"];
         currentDate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"date"];
         NSLog(@"value:%@ date:@", currentValue, currentDate); 
    }
 }
}
```